# Issue with (my potential misuse of) the Decorator Pattern

Tags: java, decorator

I am attempting to modify the behavior of my objects using the decorator pattern but have hit a bit of a snag where the decorator pattern seems to fail to be able to change the functionality of my objects the way I want.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

I have a class with a getter for an int and some other "complex" that does some computation using the getter

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private int value = 5;

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public int complexStuff() {
        return 50 + getValue();
    }
}
```

I have an abstract decorator that just passes all the calls defined by the interface to a MyClass instance

```
public abstract class MyDecorator implements MyInterface {
    private MyClass decorated;

    public MyDecorator(MyClass decorated) {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return decorated.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int complexStuff() {
        return decorated.complexStuff();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to decorate a `MyClass` instance to modify the behaviour of the `getValue()` method in such a way that `complexStuff()` is also affected.

For example if I decorate a MyClass instance like this:

```
MyDecorator myDecorator = new MyDecorator(myClassInstance) {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 100;
    }
};
```

The way I have currently implemented this a call to `myDecorator.getValue()` would return 100, but a call to `myDecorator.complexStuff()` would return 55 as if the `MyClass` instance had not been decorated. What I want is for the call to `myDecorator.complexStuff()` to return 150.

Is there a way I can modify my use of the decorator pattern to achieve my desired result? Or some other pattern/solution I can use to get this to work how I want?

Thanks

Comment: I can't fathom a pleasant way to do this without coding the `MyClass` class to support a potential switch later. Is this an acceptable approach?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: I've edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18331031/474189) below. It involves coding `MyClass` to support this kind of behavioural change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this goal using a decorator pattern. You are trying to modify the behaviour of an existing instance, which isn't going to be trivial (if even possible).

Something like the following would work:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  private ValueProvider provider = new ValueProvider() {    
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
      return 5;
    }
  };

  // (You may wish to include this method in MyInterface)
  public void setValueProvider(ValueProvider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
  }

  @Override
  public int getValue() {
      return provider.getValue();
  }

  @Override
  public int complexStuff() {
      return 50 + getValue();
  }
}
```

You can then substitute a different `ValueProvider` at runtime. A decorator class could do the substitution for you, if you want.

Comment: As I commented in another answer I want to do this with a MyClass instance I already have not one I construct, I corrected my code in my question

Comment: I see. That might be troublesome - I'll give it some thought.

Comment: unfortunately the actual objects I'm using are far more complex than this example and I want to be able to override any of their methods in this way so I don't think this solution would work very well as I would need a "Provider" for every method on the object which seems pretty awkward.

Comment: @CarlMinden So there are definitely times where the method will be called normally on *that instance*, but later you wish to decorate and alter the behaviour at runtime?

Comment: Also I want to be able to apply potentially multiple decorators to the same object affecting the same method.  In the decorator pattern I can have 2 decorators that caller super.method() then do whatever they do and they will stack nicely but I don't see a way to do that with this method.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want...although I don't know if I'm gonna get it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify `MyClass`, maybe you can derive from it and use the subclass instead? Then you can override `getValue`.

Comment: I want to do this at runtime to an existing MyClass instance

Comment: Sorry, not happening. The class is clearly not designed to give you an opportunity to dynamically intercept `getValue`, so you can't do it (without getting into really nasty things like BCEL).

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is obvious. When you call `MyDecorator.complexStuff()` is delegate this call directly to the `MyClass decorated` delegate, where `getValue()` method is not overridden, because it is overridden in `MyDecorator` which is not `MyClass`. In other words, `MyDecorator` **HAS-A** `MyClass`, but **NOT IS-A** `MyClass`.

To fix your problem, just modify `MyDecorator.complexStuff()` method. Using this, you're free to override `getValue()` method, but no `complexStuff()` method:

```
abstract class MyDecorator implements MyInterface {

    private final MyClass decorated;

    public MyDecorator(MyClass decorated) {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    // this method is overridden, and returns 100 always
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return decorated.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public final int complexStuff() {
        return decorated.complexStuff() - decorated.getValue() + getValue();
    }
}
```